# Batch download data from SSURGO

Tags: python, geology, soil, soap, ssurgo

I'm using this python code to extract data from the SSURGO database. At the moment I'm doing for a single lat long point. Would it be possible to run the query for a list of coordinates extracted from a csv file and save the results of each coordinate into a separate data frame?

```
import requests
import json
import xmltodict
import pprint
import pandas as pd

lat = "37.54189"
lon = "-120.96683"
lonLat = lon + " " + lat
url="https://SDMDataAccess.nrcs.usda.gov/Tabular/SDMTabularService.asmx"
#headers = {'content-type': 'application/soap+xml'}
headers = {'content-type': 'text/xml'}
body = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
          <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:sdm="http://SDMDataAccess.nrcs.usda.gov/Tabular/SDMTabularService.asmx">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <sdm:RunQuery>
         <sdm:Query>SELECT co.cokey as cokey, ch.chkey as chkey, comppct_r as prcent, slope_r, slope_h as slope, hzname, hzdept_r as deptht, hzdepb_r as depthb, awc_r as awc, 
                    claytotal_r as clay, silttotal_r as silt, sandtotal_r as sand, om_r as OM, dbthirdbar_r as bulk_density, wthirdbar_r as th33, ph1to1h2o_r as pH, ksat_r as sat_hidric_cond,
                    (dbthirdbar_r-wthirdbar_r)/100 as bd FROM sacatalog sc
                    FULL OUTER JOIN legend lg  ON sc.areasymbol=lg.areasymbol
                    FULL OUTER JOIN mapunit mu ON lg.lkey=mu.lkey
                    FULL OUTER JOIN component co ON mu.mukey=co.mukey
                    FULL OUTER JOIN chorizon ch ON co.cokey=ch.cokey
                    FULL OUTER JOIN chtexturegrp ctg ON ch.chkey=ctg.chkey
                    FULL OUTER JOIN chtexture ct ON ctg.chtgkey=ct.chtgkey
                    FULL OUTER JOIN copmgrp pmg ON co.cokey=pmg.cokey
                    FULL OUTER JOIN corestrictions rt ON co.cokey=rt.cokey
                    WHERE mu.mukey IN (SELECT * from SDA_Get_Mukey_from_intersection_with_WktWgs84('point(""" + lonLat + """)')) order by co.cokey, ch.chkey, prcent, deptht
        </sdm:Query>
      </sdm:RunQuery>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>"""

response = requests.post(url,data=body,headers=headers)
print("###############################################\n")
# Put query results in dictionary format
my_dict = xmltodict.parse(response.content)

# Convert from dictionary to dataframe format
soil_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict['soap:Envelope']['soap:Body']['RunQueryResponse']['RunQueryResult']['diffgr:diffgram']['NewDataSet']['Table'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function which take coordinates as input and return a dataframe:

```
import requests
import xmltodict
import pandas as pd

def soil(lat, lon):
    #lat = "37.54189"
    #lon = "-120.96683"
    lonLat = "{0} {1}".format(lon, lat)
    url="https://SDMDataAccess.nrcs.usda.gov/Tabular/SDMTabularService.asmx"
    #headers = {'content-type': 'application/soap+xml'}
    headers = {'content-type': 'text/xml'}
    body = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
              <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:sdm="http://SDMDataAccess.nrcs.usda.gov/Tabular/SDMTabularService.asmx">
       <soap:Header/>
       <soap:Body>
          <sdm:RunQuery>
             <sdm:Query>SELECT co.cokey as cokey, ch.chkey as chkey, comppct_r as prcent, slope_r, slope_h as slope, hzname, hzdept_r as deptht, hzdepb_r as depthb, awc_r as awc, 
                        claytotal_r as clay, silttotal_r as silt, sandtotal_r as sand, om_r as OM, dbthirdbar_r as bulk_density, wthirdbar_r as th33, ph1to1h2o_r as pH, ksat_r as sat_hidric_cond,
                        (dbthirdbar_r-wthirdbar_r)/100 as bd FROM sacatalog sc
                        FULL OUTER JOIN legend lg  ON sc.areasymbol=lg.areasymbol
                        FULL OUTER JOIN mapunit mu ON lg.lkey=mu.lkey
                        FULL OUTER JOIN component co ON mu.mukey=co.mukey
                        FULL OUTER JOIN chorizon ch ON co.cokey=ch.cokey
                        FULL OUTER JOIN chtexturegrp ctg ON ch.chkey=ctg.chkey
                        FULL OUTER JOIN chtexture ct ON ctg.chtgkey=ct.chtgkey
                        FULL OUTER JOIN copmgrp pmg ON co.cokey=pmg.cokey
                        FULL OUTER JOIN corestrictions rt ON co.cokey=rt.cokey
                        WHERE mu.mukey IN (SELECT * from SDA_Get_Mukey_from_intersection_with_WktWgs84('point(""" + lonLat + """)')) order by co.cokey, ch.chkey, prcent, deptht
            </sdm:Query>
          </sdm:RunQuery>
       </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>"""
    
    response = requests.post(url,data=body,headers=headers)
    print("###############################################\n")
    # Put query results in dictionary format
    my_dict = xmltodict.parse(response.content)
    
    # Convert from dictionary to dataframe format
    
    soil_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict['soap:Envelope']['soap:Body']['RunQueryResponse']['RunQueryResult']['diffgr:diffgram']['NewDataSet']['Table'])
    return soil_df

frames = []
coords = [[37.54189, -120.96683], [37.9014, -121.1895]]
for coord in coords: #For each coordinate pair, create a df and append to frames list
    frames.append(soil(*coord))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I will try it out and report back.
Many Many thanks!